# Flipping Images

Tags: python, css, image, image-processing

I am trying to complete an image editing task in my learning Python book. I need help with the horizontal flip.

The instructions are: Write a function called "flip_horizontal" which will flip the picture horizontally. That is, the pixel that is on the far right end of the row ends up on the far left of the row and vice versa (remember to preserve RGB order!).

My code does not flip the image horizontally when I open it. Also, how can I write my effects to different files (use the original file and apply one function the original file and output it, and then apply another function to the original file and output it to another file). Please, keep in mind that I am only 11 years old and have a very basic understanding of Python and image editing, it is just an interest of mine.

```
class PPM(object):
    def __init__(self, infile, outfile):
        self.infile=infile
        self.outfile=outfile

        #Read in data of image
        data= open(self.infile,"r")
        datain=data.read()
        splits=datain.split()

        #Header info
        self.type=splits[0]
        self.columns=splits[1]
        self.row=splits[2]
        self.colour=splits[3]
        self.pixels=splits[4:]

    def negate_red(self):
        for b in range (0, (len(self.pixels)) , 3):
            remainder=255-self.colour

    def writetofile(self):
        dataout= open(self.outfile,"w")
        dataout.write(self.type +"\n" + self.columns + "\n" + self.row +"\n"+ self.colour +"\n"+ " ".join (self.pixels))

    def grey_scale(self):
        if int(self.columns) > 1000:
            return "ERROR!! Number of columns is larger than what can be held in a buffer."
        else:
            for b in range(0, (len(self.pixels)) , 3):
                sum = int(self.pixels[b]) + int(self.pixels[b+1]) + int(self.pixels[b+2])
                avg = int(sum/3)

                self.pixels[b] = str(avg)
                self.pixels[b+1] = str(avg)
                self.pixels[b+2] = str(avg)

    def flatten_red(self):
        for colour in range (0,len(self.pixels),3):
            self.pixels [colour]=str(0)

    #Create a 2d lists with the smaller lists containing the rgb values and append lists of lists
    def horizontal_flip(self):
        if int(self.columns) > 1000:
            return "ERROR!! Number of columns is larger than what can be held in a buffer."
        else:
            temp_list = []
            for b in range(int(self.row)):
                column_list = []
                column_list += self.pixels[0:int(self.columns) * 3]
                self.pixels = self.pixels[int(self.columns) * 3 : ]
                temp_list.append(column_list)
            #print temp_list
            new_list = []
            for i in range(int(len(temp_list))):
                new_list.append (temp_list[i][0])
                new_list.append (temp_list[i][1])
                new_list.append (temp_list[i][2])
                temp_list[i] = temp_list[i][::-1]

sample= PPM("cake.ppm", "Replica.ppm")
sample.flatten_red()
sample.horizontal_flip()
sample.greyscale()
sample.negate_red()
```

Comment: You wrote "My code does not do anything and does flip the image horizontally when I open it." I take it you meant "*doesn't* flip the image horizontally"?

Comment: @AdiInbar- Yes, that is what I meant- Sorry

Comment: Okay, another part I'm confused about..."and then apply another function to either the original file and output it to another file"...seems like there's a missing "or" in there, as in "either the original file *or* <something>"?

Comment: @AdiInbar- Sorry the either was not supposed to be in their.

Comment: Okay, much better! :)  Good luck... (I'm not a Python expert, I'm just doing first post reviews)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image flipping and editing in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031546/image-flipping-and-editing-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a row of pixels.

i.imgur.com/1iZesZL.jpg

Now, what we want to do is to flip it so that the right-most pixel is on the left-most place, right?

So if we have the pixel on the far-left with the coordinates (x,y) then the pixel on the far-right has the coordinates (x+n, y) where n = the width of the picture in pixels.

i.imgur.com/EE7Qj5r.jpg

Now, a horizontal flip would look like this, right?

i.imgur.com/fbNLCuX.jpg

So what we do is we go from the far right and the far left, swap the values of the current pixels and go one step to the right and one step to the left until they meet in the middle.

In pseudo-code this might look something like this:

```
n = width
x = 0
y = whatever row we're on currently
while n != width/2
    temporary = (x,y) # (x,y) refers to a specific pixel in the picture
    (x,y) = (n, y)
    (n, y) = temporary
    n = n-1
    x = x+1
```

Do you think that's enough to solve the rest yourself? Wouldn't want to take the fun out of it :-)

Comment: @ejbs- The only problem is I am completely stuck and need help with the code I have already written or a complete solution which I can then use to understand where I went wrong with my solution

Comment: @ejbs- I am trying to find out what is wrong with my solution

Comment: @user3192593 I could write you a complete solution but I don't understand the datastructure that you're using. Could you explain what self.pixels contains for example?

Comment: @ejbs-  I try to form a 2 dimensional list (a list of lists). The smaller lists represent rows and consist the rgb values of the pixels in those rows. I did this because we need to flip the pixel values row wise. Now, once we have the 2d list, I access the inner lists, the rows. And then append the 3rd last, 2nd last and last rgb values in that list to a new_list. Then, i slice the original. So, we keep appending 3 values at a time and keep moving from left to right.  Eventually, the order of the pixels has been horizontally flipped while preserving  the order of the rgb values.

Comment: @ejbs-self.pixels contains all of the pixels (it is a class so I write self.pxiels)

Comment: @ejbs- It's fine if you just write it as a general function and explain it. I just want to understand the logic so I can see where I went wrong

Comment: @user3192593

Okay, I wrote this: http://pastebin.com/ZLgtJWc2

You'll have to do some changes to fix it though, because I don't know how your data structure works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really 11 years old?

It looks like each element of your `temp_list` is a column of the image to reverse the order of the columns you just have to do `temp_list = temp_list[::-1]`, but you're doing `temp_list[i] = temp_list[i][::-1]` which I think flips the image up-down (I might have it backwards though). Either way, once you get the flip, you'll need to flatten the image again and replace `self.pixels`, something like:

```
pixels = []
for column in temp_list:
    pixels.extend(column)
self.pixels = pixels
```

You're not doing much with `new_list`, I don't think you need it. Also if you want to save the image to different files, take the filename as an argument to `writetofile`, if you do that you won't need to have it in `__init__`, so something like:

```
class PPM(object):

    def __init__(self, infile):
        self.infile=infile
        # More code here

    def writetofile(self, outfile):
        dataout = open(outfile,"w")
        dataout.write(self.type +"\n" + self.columns + "\n" + self.row +"\n"+ self.colour +"\n"+ " ".join (self.pixels))
        dataout.close()

sample = PPM("cake.ppm")
sample.horizontal_flip()
sample.writetofile("Replica1.ppm")
sample.negate_red()
sample.writetofile("Replica2.ppm")
```

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe not for you since you want to practice but I came here looking for a solution to the same Problem after Research I found this and wanted to share the following: 
>   OpenCV provides a function to flip an  image.

```
void flip(array src, array dst, int flipCode)
```

Flips a 2D array around vertical, horizontal or both axes.

Parameters:

- `src` – The source Array
- `dst` – The destination array; will have the same size and same type as src
- `flipCode` – Specifies how to flip the array: 0 means flipping around the x-axis, positive (e.g., 1) means flipping around y-axis, and negative (e.g., -1) means flipping around both axes.The function flip flips the array in one of three different ways (row and column indices are 0-based).

Example code:

```
cv.flip(original_image,flip_image,1);
```